# Send range from Google spreadsheet as Email (formatting issue)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

The following code sends out an email for data in columns 2 and 3, however the results in email are not one below another.

```
Code.gs
function email() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var bulk = ss.getSheetByName("Bulk");
  var lastrow = bulk.getLastRow();

  var data1 = bulk.getRange(1, 2, lastrow).getValues();
  var data2 = bulk.getRange(1, 3, lastrow).getValues();

  var onedata="", twodata="";

  for (var i =1; i < data1.length; i++) {
    if (onedata.length) {
              onedata += ", ";
    }
   onedata += data1[i] 
  }

  for (var i =1; i < data2.length; i++) {
    if (twodata.length) {
              twodata += ", ";
    }
   twodata += data2[i] 
  }

  var report = ""

  report += "<tr><td style='padding:5px'>" + onedata + "</td><td style='padding:5px'>" + twodata + "</td></tr>";


  report ="<table><tr><th'>First data</th><th>Second data</th></tr>" + report + "</table>";

  MailApp.sendEmail(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),
                    "Your report", report, {htmlBody: report});

  }
```

Results received in email

```
First data                  Second data
Apple, Orange, Grapes,      Red, Orange, Green, Yellow,
Banana, Chickoo             Grey
```

Result expected

```
First data  Second data
Apple       Red
Orange      Orange
Grapes      Green
Banana      Yellow
Chickoo     Grey
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you made a little mistake with the for loop.

here your code with some little modifications:

```
function email() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var bulk = ss.getSheetByName("Bulk");
  var lastrow = bulk.getLastRow();

  var data1 = bulk.getRange(1, 2, lastrow).getValues(); // fruit column
  var data2 = bulk.getRange(1, 3, lastrow).getValues(); // color column

  var report = ""
  var fruitTable ="";
  for(var i in data1){
    if(data1[i]!="") fruitTable += "<tr><td style='padding:5px'>" + data1[i] + "</td><td style='padding:5px'>" + data2[i] + "</td></tr>";
  }

  report ="<table><tr><th>First data</th><th>Second data</th></tr>" + fruitTable + "</table>";

  MailApp.sendEmail(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),
                    "Your report", report, {htmlBody: report});
}
```

I hope this will respond to your needs.
Harold

Comment: Ooops, sorry, we posted almost in synch !  funny though that we came up to very similar codes ^^

Comment: Haha! indeed our answers are quite similar, but after reading your code I must admit your answer is more "sexy" with the "empty" statement.

Comment: I searched Google for a definition of "sexy code"but found nothing :-)   one should post a definition somewhere...thanks, I appreciate!!

Comment: Thank you both yours and Serge Insas answer worked, though I have used Serge's sexy code, I have marked your answer as complete, I am sure Serge would be happy with this.

Answer (score 1):

the table construction had a few errors, Below is a code with a simpler loop, feel free to adapt it the way you want... as it is it added a few features I used to make my tests easier... (style + conditions)

```
function email() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var bulk = ss.getSheetByName("Bulk");
  var lastrow = bulk.getLastRow();
  var data = bulk.getRange(1, 2, lastrow,2).getValues();  
  var tableData = "<table border=1><th>First data</th><th>Second data</th>"

  for (var i =1; i < data.length; i++) {
    var d1=data[i][0]==''?'empty ':data[i][0];
    var d2=data[i][1]==''?'empty ':data[i][1];
    tableData+="<tr><td>"+d1+"</td><td>"+d2+"</td></tr>"
  }
  tableData+="</table>";

  MailApp.sendEmail(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),
                    "Your report", "html only", {htmlBody: tableData});
}
```

---

**EDIT :**

Taking advantage of Harold's answer I added a few styles to make it more "sexy" ;-)

```
function email() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var bulk = ss.getSheetByName("Bulk");
  var lastrow = bulk.getLastRow();
  var data = bulk.getRange(1, 2, lastrow,2).getValues();  
  var tableData = '<TABLE style="border-collapse:collapse;"border = 1 cellpadding = 5 ><th style=color:blue>First data</th><th style=color:green>Second data</th>'

  for (var i =1; i < data.length; i++) {
    var d1=data[i][0]==''?'empty':data[i][0];
    var d2=data[i][1]==''?'empty':data[i][1];
    tableData+="<tr><td style=color:blue>"+d1+"</td><td style=color:green>"+d2+"</td></tr>"
  }
  tableData+="</table>";

  MailApp.sendEmail(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),
                    "Your report", "html only", {htmlBody: tableData});
}
```

Comment: Thanks Serge, it works perfect and yes it looks sexy as well. Any help for dates format, I have 10/2/2014 (10 Feb), however the result is "Thu Oct 02 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)". Can we get just "10 Feb 14" instead. :)

Comment: you can use [Utilities.formatDate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String)) to format your date.

Comment: Vasim, How do you solve this ""Thu Oct 02 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)""? can you show me how do you change the format?
In My casie: Column have "29/11/2016 10:00 " and appear "Tue Nov 29 2016 10:00:00 GMT-0300 (ART)"